# Extract / Get windows username

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

How can i Extract/Get the current username from windows?

This is what i tried:

```
Dim username As String = Application.ExecutablePath.ToString.Split("\")(0)
If username <> "" then
MsgBox(username)
End if
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the username by this method:

declare function:

```
Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
"GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, _
ByRef nSize As Integer) As Integer
```

Methods:

The Function:

```
Public Function GetUserName() As String
Dim iReturn As Integer
Dim userName As String
userName = New String(CChar(" "), 50)
iReturn = GetUserName(userName, 50)
GetUserName = userName.Substring(0, userName.IndexOf(Chr(0)))
End Function
```

Use:

```
Dim xstr As String = Space(255)
Dim max As Integer = 255
Dim rc As Integer
rc = GetUserName(xstr, max)
MessageBox.Show(Mid(xstr, 1, max))
```

The GetUserName function retrieves the name of the user associated with the current thread.

And the alternative methods:

fisrt:

```
Dim username As String = Environment.UserName
```

second:

```
Dim username2 As String = SystemInformation.UserName
```

inadvisable method:

```
MessageBox.Show(Application.ExecutablePath.ToString.Split("\")(2))
```

(you were very close! , well done.)

don't use msgbox().

msgbox is for Visual Basic 6.

MessageBox.Show is for vb.net

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this to get username:

```
 Dim username As String =
 Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)("USERNAME")
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works, if you have `System.Windows.Forms` imported:

```
 Dim username As String = SystemInformation.UserName
```